# How can I find the mean of a posterior probability?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian

There is a comet whose model show it is moving along a straight line

$$ x(t) = mt + b $$

I have the posterior predictive distribution of a comet's position, which is

$$ PPD(x) = p(x|t,d) ∝ \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} \frac{[x-Mt-B]^2}{σ^2t^2 + ξ^2}\right) $$

where $x$ is the position of the comet at some future time $t$. $M$ and $σ^2$ are the mean and variance of orbital parameter $m$, and $B$ and $ξ^2$ are the mean and variance of orbital parameter $b$.
How could I determine the most likely position of the comet at $t$ and the mean of the PPD as a function of $t$?

For the mean of the PPD, I thought the solution could be just

$$ \int t \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2} \frac{[x-Mt-B]^2}{σ^2t^2 + ξ^2}\right)dt$$

but I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: For the "most likely position" you want the value of $x$ which maximises the density (or equivalently, maximises the logarithm of the density)

Comment: I would have thought the mean would be $\int x \,p(x \mid t,d)\, dx$ and if your density is only proportional to that expression, then $\int x \,p(x \mid t,d)\, dx / \int p(x \mid t,d)\, dx$

Comment: In either case I would presume you get $\hat x = Mt+B$

Comment: @Henry for the mean, wouldn't the integral be $ \int t p(x | t,d) dt / \int p(x | t,d) dt $ since it asks for the mean to be a function of t?

Comment: I would have said $Mt+B$ was a function of $t$, but it is your question

Comment: @Henry for the most likely position, would it be possible to explain a bit more what you mean? would i just take the log of the exponential function?

Comment: You can take the logarithm, differentiate it, find where the derivative is $0$ and then check it is a maximum not a minimum.